# How to perform CRUD operations in elasticsearch with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, elasticsearch

Here my screenshot :

[image]

I want the CRUD operation like that above mentioned image.Can anyone help me with the sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Your Controller

```
//add new member
public function function_name() 
{
    //add all input fields here with key (example)
    $params = array(
     'emp_name' => $this->input->post('name'),

    );
    $add = $this->your-model-name->function_name($params);
}

//For delete member
public function function_name($id) //$id is the ID to delete member
{ 
    $delete = $this->your-model-name->function_name($id);
}

//Update member
 public function function_name($id) //$id is the ID to update member
{ 
    //all input fields of member you want to update (i.e. name)
    $params = array(
     'emp_name' => $this->input->post('name'),

    );
    $update= $this->your-model-name->function_name($id);
}
```

Your Model

```
public function function_name($params) //For add member
{
    return $this->db->insert('table-name', $params);
}

public function function_name($id) //For delete member
{
    $this->db->where('column-name', $id);
    return $this->db->delete('table-name');
}

public function function_name($id) //For update member
{
    $this->db->where('column-name', $id);
    $this->db->set('column-name', $value);
    return $this->db->update('table-name');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.!! it helps me to do it in an alternate way.

Comment: @HariFrais my pleasure